# need help to understand angular $watch

Tags: angularjs, save, watch

say I have a album list and user can add album

```
controller.albumList = function($scope, albumService) {
    $scope.albums = albumService.query();

    $scope.$watch('$scope.albums',function(){
        $scope.albums.$save($scope.albums)
    })

    $scope.addalbum= function(){
        $scope.albums.objects.push(album);   
    }
};
```

1. get a album list from server and show them
2. user can add album
3. watch the albums list ,when change happend save them to the server.

the problem is the $watch always fired, I did not even trigger the addalbum method, and every time I refresh the page a new album is created.

I follow the the code in todeMVC angular

here is the example code

```
var todos = $scope.todos = todoStorage.get();

$scope.newTodo = '';
$scope.editedTodo = null;

$scope.$watch('todos', function () {
    $scope.remainingCount = filterFilter(todos, { completed: false }).length;
    $scope.completedCount = todos.length - $scope.remainingCount;
    $scope.allChecked = !$scope.remainingCount;
    todoStorage.put(todos);
}, true);
```

please help me understand this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a solution:

```
$scope.$watch('albums', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (angular.equals(newValue, oldValue)) {
        return;
    }

    $scope.albums.$save($scope.albums);
}
```

After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due to initialization.

More about a $watch listener: [$watch at angularjs docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)

Comment: oh I see , but how come the todoMVC example works perfect fine

Comment: here is the [todoMVC controller](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/angularjs/js/controllers/todoCtrl.js)

Comment: watch should be without $scope so your code should be $scope.$watch('albums',function(newvalue,oldvalue){},true) and remember to pass true to deep watch the object

Comment: @chenliang - because the todoMVC controller use $watch with third optional parameter, in docs named as objectEquality (the last parameter, set to true), is the probably same as my reason

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you do not have to specify the scope object when referencing to a property of the scope. So, replace:

```
$scope.$watch('$scope.albums', ...)
```

with the following:

```
$scope$watch('albums', ...)
```

Now about your issue. `$watch` is triggered each time the value of the object / property being watched changes. This includes even those cases when the values are yet to be assigned, such as `undefined` and `null`. Thus, if you wish that the save should happen only when a new album is added, you can have code similar to:

```
//Makes assumption that albums has a length property
$scope.$watch('albums.length', function () {
    //Check for invalid cases
    if ($scope.albums === undefined || $scope.albums === null) {
        return;
    }

    //Genuine cases.
    //Proceed to save the album.
});
```

With this, the `$watch` is still triggered in unwanted scenarios but with the check, **you avoid saving when the album has not changed**. Also, note that your `$watch` triggers only when the length of the albums object changes. So, if an album itself is updated (say an existing album name is changed), then this watch is not triggered. You can change the watch property based on your needs. The watch property mentioned here works only when a new album is added.